# Active menu item doesn't stay colored despite li.active is set

Tags: html, css

I'm using wordpress for my website.

I'm trying to get my navigation menu items stay colored when the menu item is active.

I'm using the code below but for some reason that does not work, any idea what the issue is? (apologies if I did not put the entire code in my post but wordpress code is a bit messy - hopefully the link above will help you to assist me)

Many thanks

```
.vertical_menu .second .inner > ul > li.active > a {
color: #5599F4 !Important;
font-weight: 600 !Important;
}

.vertical_menu .second .inner > ul > li.active > a:before {
    content: "• "; 
    color: #5599F4;
margin-left: -9px;
}
```

Comment: if your'e page is loading through ajax then simply add a cass on the clicked link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to target the `current_page_item`.
Thats the class already being added to the menu item for the current page.

```
.vertical_menu .second .inner .current_page_item a {
  color: #5599F4;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.vertical_menu .second .inner .current_page_item a:before {
  content: "• "; 
  color: #5599F4;
  margin-left: -9px;
}
```